# SQL expression to scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to rewrite a spark SQL expression in scala.

```
spark.sql(
      s"""
         |SELECT
         |  *,
         |  CASE
         |    WHEN status = 'ACCEPTED' THEN 1
         |    WHEN status = 'REJECTED' THEN 2
         |    WHEN status = 'PENDING' THEN 3
         |    ELSE 0
         |  END AS updated_state
         |FROM fact_recruiter_inmail_proposal
         |""".stripMargin
    )
```

This is my rewrite which throws a syntax error

```
table.withColumn(
      "updated_state",
      .when(col("status") === "ACCEPTED", 1)
      .when(col("status") === "REJECTED", 2)
      .when(col("status") === "PENDING", 3)
      .otherwise(0)
    )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the dot before the first when:

```
  table.withColumn(
    "updated_state",
    when(col("status") === "ACCEPTED", 1)
    .when(col("status") === "REJECTED", 2)
    .when(col("status") === "PENDING", 3)
    .otherwise(0)
  )
```

This compiles